# Rounded corner only at top of image AysncImage Coil

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, coil

I'm using the new AysncImage loader for compose inside a Box.
The Box itself has a RoundedCornerShape. I have also added a RoundedCornerShape for the AsyncImage with the following values

```
Box(
            modifier = modifier

                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        ) {
            AsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(146.dp)
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 16.dp,
                        topEnd = 16.dp,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp))
                ,
                model = R.drawable.image,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            )
        }
```

But the image is rounded at all corners. [Screen Shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNLOi.png)

I don't want the image to have rounded corners at bottom.

Comment: Why do you have `clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))` on your outer box? Isn't that going to clip your `AsyncImage` on every corner no matter what modifiers you put on your `AsyncImage`?

Comment: as  #ianhanniballake said, just remove clip on AsyncImage(...) modifier, as box will clip your image automatically

Comment: @ianhanniballake removed box clip and it does what I intended thanks

Answer (score 14):

Add this modifier to your AsyncImage

```
 modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 8.dp , topStart = 8.dp))
```